# How to get an exact value from a website using php DOM and save it in a database?

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, simple-html-dom

I want to get the span id "CPH1_lblCurrent" from the url and save it in the database.
here is the code that i tried by seeing some examples.

```
<?php
$file = $DOCUMENT_ROOT. "http://www.mypetrolprice.com/2/Petrol-price-in-Delhi";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($file);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$elements = $xpath->query('//span[@id="CPH1_lblCurrent"]');
if (!is_null($elements)) {
foreach ($elements as $element) {


$nodes = $element->childNodes;
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
echo $node->nodeValue. "\n";
}
}
}
?>
```

This shows me the following.

```
Current Delhi Petrol Price = 67.12 Rs/Ltr
```

but i want only the value 67.12.

Can somebody help me.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this simple regex for getting nubmer

```
.*= ([\d.]+) .*
```

[preg_match](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: @GleacesJuvilian i have added link to preg_match function in my answer, check it :)